# ¿Cómo cambio el valor xlink:title de una etiqueta <a> que contiene un <path> en JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rutas, svg, tags

Necesito cambiar el `xlink:title` de una etiqueta `<a>`, que contiene un `<path>`, de acuerdo al valor de una variable, por ejemplo:

```
const titulo = "Título Modificado";

<a xlink:title = "Título Original"
   <path id="path1">
      ..........
   </path>
</a>
```

Así que quiero pasar el valor de la variable `titulo`, al `xlink:title` de la etiqueta `<a>`, al posicionarme con el cursor sobre el `<path>` con el id `path1`.

Y si es posible, usando jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con este código que es `mouseover`, similar a `:hover` de CSS .

En el código hay comentarios de lo que hace cada parte.

Antes de hacer algún cambio y antes de la función agregué una variable `actual` que guarda el actual texto para luego reutilizar con `mouseleave`.

Si en tu archivo **.JS** ya existe `$(document).ready(function()`, entonces cuida de no volver agregar (y su cierre).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    const titulo = "Título Modificado";
    let actual = []; // en esta variable se guarda el actual texto (Título Original)
    actual = $("a").attr("xlink:title");
    
    // Al hacer hover sobre a
    $("a").on("mouseover", function() {
        
        // Variables
        let este = $(this),
            title = este.attr("xlink:title");
        
        // Cambia en el atributo
        este.find("#path1").attr("xlink:title", title);
        
        // Cambia el texto de a
        este.find("#path1").text(titulo);
        
    // al sacar el curso sobre el mismo a   
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        
        $(this).find("#path1").attr("xlink:title", actual);
        $(this).find("#path1").text(actual);
    })
   
});
```

Comment: Gracias por la amplia explicación! Me solucionó el problema, te lo agradezco muchísimo.